# Align image to bottom of div

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a div in panel. I add a Image to this.

I wanted to align the images to the bottom of the DIV container.(show image in a line.)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="product" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <div style="float: right; width: 180px; height: 177px; margin: 0 30PX 10px 5px">
         <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <font color="white">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label></font>
            <br />
            <div style="height:140px ; overflow:hidden">
               <asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server"  Width="120px" ImageUrl='<%#  Eval("Image") %>' ImageAlign="Bottom" />
           </div>
        </asp:Panel>
     </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: please clear your requirement u want set image below div or inside div to the bottom part

Comment: I want set image bottom of div.

Comment: <font color="white"> ? font element is deprecated... not supported in HTML5. Use CSS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on the asp ImageAlign property. Use CSS, like:

```
<div style="float: right; width: 180px; height: 177px; margin: 0 30px 10px 5px; position:relative">
   <div id="panel"
        <label>Name</label>
        <img id="Image1" src='img-url-goes-here' style="position:absolute;bottom:0px;height:40px;display:block;" />
    </div>
</div>​
```

In your code it would be:

```
<div style="float: right; width: 180px; height: 177px; margin: 0 30px 10px 5px;">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <font color="white">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>    
        </font>
        <div style="overflow:hidden;height:140px; position:relative;">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server"  Width="120px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>' style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; height:40px; display:block;" />
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i use this but don't show image bottom of div. it is show top of div :(

Comment: Thanks, but id on't set height for image ... i use this code but my image set botton of main div and show image on the label.

Comment: Thanks, i use but don't work .. set div bottom of Repeater but image is top of div :(

Comment: @NilooRg I think i understood what you want. Check the latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align:bottom` in your image div

```
<asp:Repeater ID="product" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <div style="float: right; width: 180px; height: 177px; margin: 0 30PX 10px 5px">
             <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                <font color="white">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label></font>
                <br />
                <div style="height:140px ; overflow:hidden; vertical-align:bottom">
                   <asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server"  Width="120px" ImageUrl='<%#  Eval("Image") %>' ImageAlign="Bottom" />
               </div>
            </asp:Panel>
         </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```